# Reset all votes on a content type every week

Tags: rating

I am trying to build a website where people vote on individual nodes of a content type using the rate module. Is it possible to reset these votes say every 7 days or every 30 days, so that another round of voting can take place. How would I do this within drupal. I do not want to have to go through phpmyadmin to clear the voting api cache. I would prefer if this is done from within the website I'm building.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

There's many ways to accomplish this. The voting data for the Voting API module is stored in the `votingapi_vote` & `votingapi_cache` tables. Essentially, you need a way to target the vote data you wish to eliminate in these tables (e.g. via a DB query) and then build some process on which to regularly execute it (e.g. a cron run).

A crude example would be a custom module that evokes [`hook_cron()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_cron/7.x) to check the last query execution and fire it if it hits its time threshold:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_cron().
 */
function MYMODULE_cron() {

  // Clear the vote every week.
  $vote_clear_timestamp = variable_get('MYMODULE_vote_clear_timestamp', 0);
  if ($vote_clear_timestamp <= strtotime('-1 week')) {

    // A more targeted process would use db_delete() to target criteria
    db_query("TRUNCATE {votingapi_vote}");
    db_query("TRUNCATE {votingapi_cache}");
    variable_set('MYMODULE_vote_clear_timestamp', time());
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not very good with writing custom modules, please could you guide me

Comment: Drupal Answers isn't a tutorial site. Google for tutorials on creating a module in D7 or take a look at the [examples](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples) module. The code is pretty straight forward for D7; you need a ***mymodule.info*** & ***mymodule.module*** file with the cron function in the ***mymodule.module***

Comment: Ok, I think I understand what you're saying now. The question now is how to limit it per content type